# How to store the current value of the array in a variable inside a Perl for loop

Tags: arrays, perl, cgi

My requirement is, I want to map some checklist values to some groups. The following is my code:

```
@selectbox1 => contains the selected select groups
@selectbox2 => contains selected checklist
```

Code:

```
foreach $select1(@selectbox1) {
      my $sql_select1 = "select id from group_management where group_name = '$select1'";
      my $box1 = $dbslave -> prepare($sql_select1);
      $box1 -> execute();
      while($select_box1= $box1->fetchrow_array())
      {
          push (@box1,$select_box1);
      }
      my $box_1 = @box1;  # currently I tried like this to store the current value .NEED CORRECTION HERE

      foreach $select2(@selectbox2) {

        my $sql_select2 = "select id from checklist where checklist_name = '$select2'";
        my $box2 = $dbslave -> prepare($sql_select2);
        $box2 -> execute();

        while($select_box2 = $box2->fetchrow_array())
        {
            push (@box2,$select_box2);
        }
        my $box_2 = @box2;  # currently I tried like this to store the current value .NEED CORRECTION HERE

        my $sql_insert = "insert into checklist_group_mapping values ('',$box_2,$box_1)";
        my $ins = $dbslave -> prepare($sql_insert);
        $ins -> execute();
      }
}
```

How can I assign the current value of the array to a variable so that I can insert it into the mapping table?

Comment: First, use `placeholders` or it gets ugly. Second, is `$dbslave` your database handle?

Comment: yeah...$dbslave is the database handle .i just want , how to take the current value for insertion :
need correction in the following places : my $box_1 = @box1 and my $box_2 = @box2;

Comment: Are you using `DBI` and are you getting errors?

Comment: i am not getting any errors, for the insertion i need the correct value, thats all

Comment: Ok, the correct value from your array or the database? What value is being returned right now?

Comment: @Jenifer_justin Are you using `use strict; use warnings;`? (I would guess no) If not, add them, fix the warnings/errors, then post the updated code.

Comment: my issue fixed.Thanks alot for your immediate response :)

my requirement was this :  my $box_1 = $box1[-1];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read up on 'context', and in particular 'scalar context' and 'array context'.

When you write:

```
  my $box_1 = @box1;
```

you are providing scalar context, and in scalar context, `@box1` returns the number of elements in the array.  If you wrote:

```
  my($box_1) = @box1;
```

you would be providing array context, and in array context, the first element of `@box1` would be assigned to the first element of the array context, `$box_1` — and the remaining elements of `@box1` would be dropped. (This may well be what you're after; it is likely that you are trying to select the single ID value for each of the various names in `@selectbox1`.)

Judging from how you're trying to use the `$box_1` and `$box_2` variables in your code, you are looking to obtain a single string containing all the values from `@box1` and another single string containing all the values from `@box2`, and they probably need to be presented to the DBI driver enclosed in single quotes.

You can get space-separated values into a string using:

```
my $box_1 = "@box1";
```

If you need comma-separated values, you can use:

```
my $box_1;
{ local $" = ","; $box_1 = "@box_1"; }
```

The `$"` (aka `$LIST_SEPARATOR` under `use English '-no_match_vars';`) must be localized to prevent damage, but that means you have to separate the definition of `$box_1` from the assignment (because if you don't, `$box_1` is destroyed when you leave the `{...}` block).

Now, to protect that so that the SQL can work, you need to use the [`quote`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.627/DBI.pm#quote) method:

```
$box1 = $dbslave->quote($box1);
```

or:

```
my $box1 = $dbslave->quote("@box1");
```

Assembling these changes, we get:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

### Improved, but not operational

# use DBI;

my @selectbox1 = ( "group1", "group2", "group3" );
my @selectbox2 = ( "check1", "check2", "check3" );
my $dbslave;

# $dbslave = DBI->connect(...) or die "A horrible death";

foreach my $select1 (@selectbox1)
{
    my $sql_select1 = "select id from group_management where group_name = '$select1'";
    my $box1 = $dbslave->prepare($sql_select1);
    $box1->execute();
    my @box1;
    while (my $select_box1 = $box1->fetchrow_array())
    {
        push @box1, $select_box1;
    }
    my $box_1 = $dbslave->quote("@box1");

    foreach my $select2(@selectbox2)
    {
        my $sql_select2 = "select id from checklist where checklist_name = '$select2'";
        my $box2 = $dbslave->prepare($sql_select2);
        $box2->execute();

        my @box2;
        while (my $select_box2 = $box2->fetchrow_array())
        {
            push @box2, $select_box2;
        }
        my $box_2 = $dbslave->quote("@box2");

        my $sql_insert = "insert into checklist_group_mapping values ('', $box_2, $box_1)";
        my $ins = $dbslave->prepare($sql_insert);
        $ins->execute();
    }
}
```

Note that the two SELECT statements assume that the select box strings contain no funny characters (specifically, no single quotes).  If you're in charge of the content of `@selectbox1` and `@selectbox2`, that's OK.  If they contain user input, you have to sanitize that input, or use `$dbslave->quote()` again, or use place-holders.  I'm going to ignore the issue.

You are also using scalar context with `$box1->fetchrow_array()`, which is not going to yield the answer you want (although `fetchrow_array()` is context sensitive, the [manual](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.627/DBI.pm#fetchrow_array) warns you to be careful).  I would use something like:

```
    my @box1;
    while (my @row = $box1->fetchrow_array())
    {
        push @box1, $row[0];
    }
    my $box_1 = $dbslave->quote("@box1");
```

You also need to use functions.  There's a glaring repeat in your code that can be encapsulated into a single function used twice:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# use DBI;

my @selectbox1 = ( "group1", "group2", "group3" );
my @selectbox2 = ( "check1", "check2", "check3" );
my $dbslave;

# $dbslave = DBI->connect(...) or die "A horrible death";

sub fetch_all
{
    my($dbh, $sql) = @_;
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
    my @results;
    while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array())
    {
        push @results, $row[0];
    }
    my $result = $dbslave->quote("@results");
    return $result;
}

foreach my $select1 (@selectbox1)
{
    my $sql_select1 = "select id from group_management where group_name = '$select1'";
    my $box_1 = fetch_all($dbslave, $sql_select1);

    foreach my $select2(@selectbox2)
    {
        my $sql_select2 = "select id from checklist where checklist_name = '$select2'";
        my $box_2 = fetch_all($dbslave, $sql_select2);

        my $sql_insert = "insert into checklist_group_mapping values ('', $box_2, $box_1)";
        my $ins = $dbslave->prepare($sql_insert);
        $ins->execute();
    }
}
```

The INSERT statement should be converted to use placeholders so it can be prepared once and used many times:

```
my $sql_insert = "insert into checklist_group_mapping values ('', ?, ?)";
my $ins = $dbslave->prepare($sql_insert);

foreach my $select1 (@selectbox1)
{
    my $sql_select1 = "select id from group_management where group_name = '$select1'";
    my $box_1 = fetch_all($dbslave, $sql_select1);

    foreach my $select2(@selectbox2)
    {
        my $sql_select2 = "select id from checklist where checklist_name = '$select2'";
        my $box_2 = fetch_all($dbslave, $sql_select2);
        $ins->execute($box_1, $box_2);
    }
}
```

Indeed, the two SELECT statements should also be parameterized and prepared once and reused.  I've not shown that change because (a) I'm lazy and (b) there's a bigger change that is still more effective.

When we look at what you're really doing, it should all be a single SQL statement:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# use DBI;

my @selectbox1 = ( "group1", "group2", "group3" );
my @selectbox2 = ( "check1", "check2", "check3" );
my $dbslave;

# $dbslave = DBI->connect(...) or die "A horrible death";

sub placeholder_list
{
    my($n) = @_;
    die "$n should be larger than 0" if $n <= 0;
    my $list = "(?" . ",?" x ($n - 1) . ")";
    return $list;
}

my $sql_insert = qq%
    INSERT INTO checklist_group_mapping(col1, col2, col3)
        SELECT '', gm.id, cl.id
          FROM group_management AS gm
         CROSS JOIN checklisst AS cl
         WHERE gm.group_name IN X1
           AND cl.checklist_name IN X2
%;

my $X1 = placeholder_list(scalar(@selectbox1));
my $X2 = placeholder_list(scalar(@selectbox2));
$sql_insert =~ s/X1/$X1/;
$sql_insert =~ s/X2/$X2/;

my $ins = $dbslave->prepare($sql_insert);
$ins->execute(@selectbox1, @selectbox2);
```

The big advantage of this is that there are far fewer round trips for information flowing between the application and the database, which (almost) invariably improves performance, often dramatically.

The only residual issue is whether your DBMS supports explicit CROSS JOIN like that.  If not, you'll need to replace the words CROSS JOIN with a single comma.

There are still things that should be fixed, such as checking that the prepared statements were successfully prepared, and so on.  But this may have given you some insight into how to think about using the DBI with Perl.

Comment: Nice job.But I have a feeling that the OP won't even read this.

Comment: Thanks.  There's always that risk, but one lives in hope.  Since there's a note from the OP that `my $box_1 = $box1[-1];` solved her problem, you're more probably correct than I'd like to think.  I should probably have noted that the cross-join isn't a particularly good idea, either.  It usually isn't the best solution to any particular problem.  However, that's an application level issue rather then the techie nuts and bolts solution of how to get the cross-joined data into a table which the code fragment achieves long-windedly.

Comment: Jonathan, believe me, I was not intending to sabotage your hopes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind effort....really amazing one.....i changed my previous concept and used this.:)

Answer (score -4):

The trick is to use **$**_ variable inside your **foreach**. Like this:

```
  my $current_value;
  foreach $select2(@selectbox2) {
        $current_value = $_;
        my $sql_select2 = "select id from checklist where checklist_name = '$select2'";
```

......

```
my $box_2 = $current_value;
```

Comment: `$_` is not set by the `foreach` loop. The `foreach` sets `$select2` to the array values. Hence the declaration of `$current_value` outside the loop and the assignment inside are not useful.